# SQL join or union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 union query already done, the issue is it prints out the entire course list from the database. here is my statement:

```
SELECT id, parent, name, 'category' AS `type`
FROM course_categories
UNION ALL
SELECT ( 1000 + id ) AS id, category, fullname, 'fullname' AS `type`
FROM course
```

I want to join with this table:

org_courses
id
orgid
courseid

I'm having issues getting the correct results and I'm trying to keep the aliases the same in the first query because i have a rendertree function that prints these out in a nice ul, li, so i'm tryng not to have to rewrite it. Any help in joining these is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the first one in a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, parent, name, 'category' AS `type`
  FROM course_categories
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ( 1000 + id ) AS id, category, fullname, 'fullname' AS `type`
  FROM course
) courses
INNER JOIN org_courses 
  ON org_course.courseid = courses.id
```

Comment: this one works a little better, however, it still seems to be pulling only the parent categories and not the courses under them. I am using a where clause at the end where orgid= 9. with or without the where clause it still only pulls the category list and not courses under

Comment: @Ansipants - If you're going to keep relevant information out of your question, then why would you expect a relevant answer?

Comment: agai, either way, with or without, it still pulls the category list only